# How to query likes and user details for posts?

Tags: database-design, query, normalization, sqlite

I'm pretty new to the world of databases and SQL.

I'm trying to build a system for users to **submit posts and like posts**. I've been looking at a few similar questions on this site, reading about third normal form, etc. and I think I have a pretty solid DB schema at this point:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERPROFILES (
  ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  USERNAME VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL_ADDRESS VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  COUNTRY_CODE CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  CREATED_DATE DATETIME(9) NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE USERPROFILES ADD CONSTRAINT USERPROFILES_USERNAME_UNIQUE UNIQUE (USERNAME)
ALTER TABLE USERPROFILES ADD CONSTRAINT USERPROFILES_EMAIL_ADDRESS_UNIQUE UNIQUE (EMAIL_ADDRESS)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERPOSTS (
  ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  THREAD_ID INT NOT NULL,
  PARENT_POST_ID INT NULL,
  PROFILE_ID INT NOT NULL,
  WRITTEN_TEXT VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  MEDIA_LOCATION VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  CREATED_DATE DATETIME(9) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_USERPOSTS_PROFILE_ID__ID FOREIGN KEY (PROFILE_ID) REFERENCES USERPROFILES(ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERVOTES (
  POST_ID INT,
  PROFILE_ID INT,
  CREATED_DATE DATETIME(9) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_UserVotes PRIMARY KEY (POST_ID, PROFILE_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_USERVOTES_POST_ID__ID FOREIGN KEY (POST_ID) REFERENCES USERPOSTS(ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT FK_USERVOTES_PROFILE_ID__ID FOREIGN KEY (PROFILE_ID) REFERENCES USERPROFILES(ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
```

Now what I want to do is perform a single query for my application to fetch all `USERPOSTS` with a given `THREAD_ID` (on behalf of a requesting user), but also join with the `USERVOTES` and `USERPROFILES` tables such that I can get **a list of posts combined with the following data**:

- total like count for the post
- if the requesting user liked the post or not
- the username of the submitter of the post (not just their userprofile ID)

With this I can render everything I need in the application.

**Can anyone help construst a single query like this given my table schema?** I'm assuming I will need at least two INNER JOINs (one on USERVOTES and one on USERPROFILE) as well as a COUNT on the USERVOTES (but also, in addition, how do I query USERVOTES with a WHERE for a specific requesting USERID)?

Thanks!

Comment: you would use `LEFT JOINS`, because there may not be a vote. `SUM(USERVOTES.PROFILE_ID={cost}) as Xvoted`  will show if a specific user voted.

Comment: "*total like count for the post*" - Where do you store *likes* in your schema?...is the mere existence of there being a record in the `USERVOTES` table representative of a *like*?...if so, then the `USERVOTES` table will never store *dislikes* or other types of *voting*?

Comment: @J.D. yes, that is correct. Perhaps I should rename this table to `USERLIKES` - because there is only one kind of vote (a like)

Comment: @idolize Yes probably makes more sense, and if I'm giving away my 2 cents, I don't see a need to prefix everything with the word `USER`. In fact, the *likes* describe the *posts* not the *users* so if you're looking for a prefix, I'd actually name it `PostLikes` to be more clear.

Comment: Good point - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick (note the aliases, and feel free to adjust the casing to your preferred format):

```
SELECT 
    Posts.ID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Likes.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS TotalLikesCount,
    SubmitterProfiles.USERNAME,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Likes.PROFILE_ID = 98765 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DidRequestingUserLikeThisPost
FROM USERPOSTS AS Posts
INNER JOIN USERPROFILES AS SubmitterProfiles -- Inner Join should since a Post must be submitted by a User
    Posts.PROFILE_ID = SubmitterProfiles.ID
LEFT JOIN USERVOTES AS Likes -- Outer (Left) Join because not all Posts necessarily have Likes
    ON Posts.ID = Likes.POST_ID
LEFT JOIN USERPROFILES AS VoterProfiles -- Need to continue with an Outer (Left) Join here because we're pulling the profile of the User who liked the Post (if there is a like)
    ON Likes.PROFILE_ID = VoterProfiles.ID
WHERE Posts.THREAD_ID = 12345
GROUP BY Posts.ID, SubmitterProfiles.USERNAME
```

Please read the comments for more information, but basically this starts with your `USERPOSTS` table and inner joins your `USERPROFILES` table (which should always have a many-to-one relationship), then outer joins the remaining information (because some posts may not have likes).

Since the relationship between `USERPOSTS` and `USERVOTES` is one-to-many (when there are likes) the results set becomes a single row per like, so we need to group up by the `ID` of the post so we can *count* how many likes (rows) there are which I'm doing using the `SUM()` function with a `CASE` statement to handle `NULL` cases (when there's no likes for a given post).

We also have to group by the `USERPROFILES.USERNAME` so that we can `SELECT` it and this doesn't change the cardinality of our results, since every post can only be submitted by a single user.

Comment: Thank you! I'm dissecting this now and it generally makes a lot of sense. Only question I have is how would I also get not only the total likes for each post, but also a boolean for if the specific requesting user liked the post or not? I'm thinking it would be another `CASE` in the `SELECT`? Perhaps `,CASE WHEN Likes.ID = 12345 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE AS ReqUserLiked`

Comment: @idolize Sorry I missed that criteria. But I think I updated my answer to account for that now. Correct you'd need a `CASE` statement for that and this time using the `MAX()` aggregate function to see if any of the likes was the requesting user by the `PROFILE_ID`. Note SQLite doesn't have a boolean data type so typical convention is to use the integer data type it has and return 1 for true and 0 for false.

Comment: @idolize Also I just noticed your table definitions use data types that don't exist in SQLite either. Please see [Data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for more information on which types exist so you can pick the appropriate one's for your tables.

Comment: Amazing - makes sense. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @idolize No problem at all, best of luck!